# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not set

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python coding so excuse my ignorance. 
I am making a web scraper as test project but I have an issue with a portion of it where I'm trying to make a integer variable.

```py
episodes = example_soup.findAll("p", {"class": "short-desc"})
ep = len(episodes)
print(ep)
for p in episodes:

    title = episodes[{ep}].text.strip() ### <---- Issue [{ep}] <---TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not set

    print(title)
```

Comment: This cannot work: A) `[{ep}]` - you're using a single value set (`{}` makes a set) as an index; B) changed to `[ep]` won't work because `ep = len(episodes)`, i.e. it's larger by 1 than the largest index. I'm guessing what you want it `title = p.text.strip()` as @ex4 suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If your episodes is list of objects you can do like this

```
for p in episodes:
    title = p.text.strip()
```

When you loop through the list you get elements, not index.

`{p}` creates set with p as an only item. 
You can read basics of sets from https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to index the `episodes` list with `[{ep}]` but it must be a number.
you probably meant to `[ep]`.

```
LIST = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(LIST[0]) # result = 1
print(LIST[{0}]) # TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not set
```

Comment: I tried using what you suggested with doing [ep] but it gives me a IndexError: list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

````
while time.time() < t_end:
    # do whatever you do
    eplist -=1
    title = episodes[eplist]

    time.sleep(1)
    eps = title.text.strip()

    print("Episode:" + " " + eps)```
````